# What does scanf do when passing a char and an integer specifier?

Tags: c, scanf

For the purposes of an exercise, I was given a snippet of code and told to find the bug. I removed a bunch of noise and the part that is tripping me up is the following:

```
int main() {
    char *p;
    char n;
    scanf("%i", n);
    if (n < get_int()) {
        p = malloc(n);
    }
}
```

Here, if I enter a number for `n`, I get a seg fault. If I enter a character, `n` is set to `0`. What is `scanf` doing that makes this so?

Edit: the exercise I'm trying to figure out is Exercise 2 from [this page](http://www-verimag.imag.fr/%7Emounier/Enseignement/Software_Security/td3.pdf)

Comment: `What is scanf doing that makes this so?` Basically something along `if (input is a number) { *(int*)n = that_number; } else return;`

Comment: first `scanf("%i", n);` must be `scanf("%i", &n);` and second *n* must be an `int` rather than a `char`, else you have an undefined behavior. Then if you do not enter a number *n* is not initialized by *scanf* whose return 0 rather than 1

Comment: You cannot use `scanf()` correctly unless you ***check the return***. E.g. `if (scanf ("%i", &n) != 1) { /* handle error */ }` Regarding `n` if you check the man page for `scanf()` and the `"%i"` conversion specifier `"the next pointer must be a pointer to int"`

Comment: @bruno I know what it must be, but like I said, for the purpose of an exercise this is what I'm given. The whole point is eventually p is allocated 0 bytes in memory and I do a strcpy from a char[] to p, hence overflowing it. I would like to know why scanf behaves as it does given the above scenario.

Comment: @biscuitduke like the code is you have an undefined behavior in **all cases** (whatever your input) and **nothing** more can be say

Comment: Think of it this way, with `"%i"` you are writing 4-bytes to the address of `n` that is only 1-byte in size.

Comment: @biscuitduke so the vulnerabilities are explained in the remarks above ;)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin *scanf* does not write in *n* except if its not initialized value (also reading out of it) is miraculously its address ;) there is no '&'

Comment: @bruno - note the inclusion of `'&'` in my comment above. The second comment relates to the first.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply UB.

C does not specify any specific behavior here. `"%i"` expect a `int *`, not an uninitialized  `char` converted to an `int`.

"What is scanf doing that makes this so?" implies defined behavior.  There is no specified UB.

---

"If I enter a character, n is set to 0. " --> `scanf()` does not attempt to change `n`, it uses a copy of `n` (passed by value).

The usual `scanf()` usages is like the below where the *address* of `nn` is passed, not `nn` itself.

```
int nn;
if (scanf("%i", &nn) == 1) Success();
else Failure();
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't just passing the wrong kind of variable to scanf, you are also passing it's **value** instead of the pointer to it. The scanf have no way of knowing this value isn't an actual pointer to store the scanned data into, so thats exactly what its going to try and do, scan the input and place it into whatever memory address the n, treated as pointer value, happened to point to. In the absolute most of the cases this will attempt to access unmapped/protected/etc memory, and cause segfault/access violation.

Entering a character simply terminates the scan prematurely, avoiding the segfault, and leaving the n intact. Bit since the value of n isn't initialized, it can happen to be just about anything, any junk that happened to be on the stack at that point of time.